# How to call a method from outside app-root in angular6

Tags: angular

How to call method `getAlert()` from outside `<app-root>` where method is defined in `app.component.ts`

Note: The requirement is the method `getAlert('4')` is being called from outside `<app-root>`

## index.html

```
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="getAlert('4')">call</button>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

## app.component.ts

```
function getAlert(data) {
alert(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As maxJohnson suggested, you can move your `button` to your `app.component.html`

Also now you need to use `(click)` instead of `onclick` to trigger component `getAlert` method

Your code will be like this:

**app.component.html**

```
<button type="button" (click)="getAlert('4')">call</button>
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
getAlert(data) {
alert(data);
}
```

**Update**

If you want to go with your approach, you can assign your function to a global(`window`) object like this:

**app.component.ts**

```
contructor(private zone: NgZone) {
 window.componentRef = {
      zone: this.zone, 
      componentFn: (value) => this.getAlert(value), 
      component: this
    };
}
```

[`NgZone`](https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone) is used for change detection because Angular will not be notified when model changes outside of Angular Component.

Don't forget to destroy it using `NgDestroy`

Now in your javascript you can defined a function like this:

```
function handleClick(value) {
  window['componentRef'].zone.run(() =>{
   window['componentRef'].component.getAlert(value);
  })
}
```

And in your **index.html**

```
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="handleClick('4')">call</button>
<app-root></app-root>

<script>
  function handleClick(value) {
  window['componentRef'].zone.run(() =>{
   window['componentRef'].component.getAlert(value);
  })
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: the method is called outside app-root , that's a requirement.

Comment: Don't forget to destroy it using NgDestroy. How to achieve this?

Comment: @Mahi [here](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/angular-2-component-lifecycle-hooks-fa5a84b4b64d) is a helpful article

Comment: I think, for above question , we dont need ngOnDestroy(), it has different use case.

Comment: @Mahi ngOnDestroy() is used to clean up data or code or unsubscribing from any observables. In this case,we should remove the component reference from `window` object as the component will no longer exist

Answer (score 1):

I would consider moving the `<button type="button" onclick="getAlert('4')">call</button>` to the `app.component.html` file. Then you should be able to call the function from the component `app.component.ts`.